# Mark words in notepad++ including dash (-)

Tags: search, notepad++

I would like to mark in Notepad++ the sql scripts in a text log. The sql files have this format in the text:

```
AAAAAAAA.BBBBBBBBBBB.sql
```

So what I execute is this sentence in search menu:

```
\w*.sql
```

As I should get **BBBBBBBBBBB.sql**. The point is that in some script names there are dashes (-), and when that happens I dont get the whole name, but just the end after the last dash.

For example, in:

```
AAAAAAAA.BBBBB-CCCCCCC.sql
```

I would like to get **BBBBB-CCCCCCC.sql**, but I just get **CCCCCCC.sql**

Is there any possible formula to get them?

Comment: Like this? `\w+(?:-\w+)*\.sql` See https://regex101.com/r/XPDLiA/1 Can the match start or end with a `-` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the match can not start and end with a hyphen:

```
\w+(?:-\w+)*\.sql
```

- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:-\w+)*` Optionally match `-` and 1+ word characters
- `\.sql` Match `.sql`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XPDLiA/1).

**Note** that in your pattern the `\w*` can also match 0 occurrences and that the `.` can match any character if it is not escaped.

---

Another option could be using a character class to match either `-` or a word character, but this would also allow to mix and match like `--a--.sql`

```
[\w-]+\.sql
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQ3aka/1).